# Does a Mutation count as a campaign?

Tags: left-4-dead-2, achievements, mods

In left 4 dead 2, there's currently a mutation called Four Swordsmen, where you can only use a sword to play the level.

I was wondering if finishing a level would award me the Confederacy Of Crunches achievement (Finish a campaign using only melee weapons).

I ask because there are no common infected on this mutation, so perhaps it doesn't count towards it, being different to a "normal" campaign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it should count towards the normal campaign. My friends and I have played the mutations every week so far. The first week, we were all able to get the achievement for crossing the bridge in under 3 minutes in The Parish because there wasn't a full number of common infected. We also all received credit for chainsaw kills during the chainsaw event, so I presume that you should be able to get full credit for Confederacy of Crunches.

Comment: Confirmed. I've earned it too.

Comment: I did not earn it, could it be because I "took a break"? /cc @Arda

Comment: Did you make sure that you never shot your pistols once you were incapped? That will invalidate the achievement. Checking the L4D wiki, on the Mutations page, if you scroll all the way to the bottom, they have a note saying that CoC is easier to get in 4 Swordsman mode.
http://left4dead.wikia.com/wiki/Mutations

Comment: I had fired the gun =( - I'll have to play it again then... Would I receive it if I don't fire no matter that the gun spawns in my hand?

Comment: And and additional +1 for that mutations link

Comment: Yep, you will receive it, as long as you don't fire. Doesn't matter that it appears in your hand at all, just don't click. I am guilty of screwing that up several times myself from habit!

Comment: Also, you can use molotovs/pipes/bile jars, they won't hurt the achievement progress. Careful, though, killing an infected with them might ruin it. Haven't tested them yet.